# how to make web service run to finish even if user leaves page

Tags: c#, .net, ajax

I have a website where I need to take a bit of data from the user, make an ajax call to a .net webservice, and then the webservice does some work for about 5-10 minutes.

I naturally dont want the user to have to sit there that whole time, so I have made it an asynchronous ajax call to the webservice, and after the call has been sent, I redirect the user to a "you are done!" page.

What I want to happen is for the webservice to keep running to finish--and not abort--after it receives the information from the user.

From my testing, this is more or less what happens, but now I'm finding that this might be limited by time? I.e. if the webservice runs past a certain amount of time, it will abort if the user isnt still connected.

I might be off here in this assessment, but this is what I THINK is going on from my testing.

So my question is whether with .net web services, if this is indeed what happens? Does it get aborted after some time if the user isnt still on the other end? Is there any way to disable this abort?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How long would you estimate is the max amount of time that the web service needs to be able to finish the job?

Comment: I think at most 10-15 minutes right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you invoke a web service, it will always finish its work, even if user leaves the page that invoked it.

Of course webservices have their own configuration and one of them sets timeout.

If you're creating a WCF service (SOAP Service) you can set it in its contract (changing binding properties), if you're creating a service with WebApi or MVC (REST/Http Service) then you can either add to its config file or programmatically set in its controller as it follows.

`HttpContext.Server.ScriptTimeout = 3600; //Number of seconds`

That can be a reason causing webservice to interrupt its work but it is not related to what happens on client side.

Have a nice day,

Alberto

Comment: Alberto, thank you so much! I think you are nailing the answer here. Let me see if I can pick your brain a bit. I'm new to webservice development, so some of the terminology is going over my head. I've created not WCF webservice, but the ASMX type. Would you happen to know where would i just the settings in something like?

Comment: The short answer for your question is:
you don't have to do anything, any server-side method create with any server-side technology is completely executed from start to end. Of course if exceptions (TimeoutExeption for example) are thrown and not catched, the execution will terminate with failure. :)

Answer (score 0):

> Whilst I agree that the answer here is technically correct, I just
>   wanted to post a more robust alternative approach that avoids some of
>   the pitfalls possible with your current approach such as

- Web Server being bounced during the long-running processing of request
- Web Server App pool being recycled during processing
- Web server running out of threads due to too many long-running requests and not being able to process any more requests

> I would recommend you take a thoroughly ansynchronous approach and use
>   Message Queues (MSMQ for example) with a trigger on the queue that
>   will execute the work.

The process would be:

- Your page makes Ajax call to the Webservice
- Webservice writes a message into the Queue and returns right away. The message contains details of what work needs to be carried out.
- User continues on your site as usual, or goes home, etc.

> A trigger on the Queue is watching for messages and when a message
>   arrives in the queue, it activates a process which:

- Reads the message
- Performs the necessary work
- Updates any back-end storage, etc, with the results of the work

This is much more robust because it totaly decouples the Web service from any long-running work and means that if the user makes a request and the web server goes down a moment later (for whatever reason) then the work will still be queued up when the server comes back online, etc.

You can read more about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms711472%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (MSMQ is the MS Message Queue tech; there are many others!)

Just my 2c

Comment: Thanks for this! I'll definitely take a look and see if I can implement.

Comment: Cool. And if you run into problems, you know where to ask!